# How to transfer a value from a function in one script to another script without re-running the function (python)?

Tags: python, flask, transfer

I'm really new to programming in general and very inexperienced, and I'm learning python as I think it's more simple than other languages.  Anyway, I'm trying to use Flask-Ask with ngrok to program an Alexa skill to check data online (which changes a couple of times per hour).  The script takes four different numbers (from a different URL) and organizes it into a dictionary, and uses Selenium and phantomjs to access the data.

Obviously, this exceeds the 8-10 second maximum runtime for an intent before Alexa decides that it's taken too long and returns an error message (I know its timing out as ngrok and the python log would show if an actual error occurred, and it invariably occurs after 8-10 seconds even though after 8-10 seconds it should be in the middle of the script).  I've read that I could just reprompt it, but I don't know how and that would only give me 8-10 more seconds, and the script usually takes about 25 seconds just to get the data from the internet (and then maybe a second to turn it into a dictionary).

I tried putting the getData function right after the intent that runs when the Alexa skill is first invoked, but it only runs when I initialize my local server and just holds the data for every new Alexa session.  Because the data changes frequently, I want it to perform the function every time I start a new session for the skill with Alexa.

So, I decided just to outsource the function that actually gets the data to another script, and make that other script run constantly in a loop.  Here's the code I used.

```
import time

def getData():
  username = '' #username hidden for anonymity
  password = '' #password hidden for anonymity
  browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/phantomjs')
  browser.get("https://gradebook.com") #actual website name changed
  browser.find_element_by_name("username").clear()
  browser.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys(username)
  browser.find_element_by_name("password").clear()
  browser.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(password)
  browser.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
  global currentgrades
  currentgrades = []
  gradeids = ['2018202', '2018185', '2018223', '2018626', '2018473', '2018871', '2018886']
  for x in range(0, len(gradeids)):
    try:
        gradeurl = "https://www.gradebook.com/grades/"
        browser.get(gradeurl)
        grade = browser.find_element_by_id("currentStudentGrade[]").get_attribute('innerHTML').encode('utf8')[0:3]
        if grade[2] != "%":
            grade = browser.find_element_by_id("currentStudentGrade[]").get_attribute('innerHTML').encode('utf8')[0:4]
        if grade[1] == "%":
            grade = browser.find_element_by_id("currentStudentGrade[]").get_attribute('innerHTML').encode('utf8')[0:1]
        currentgrades.append(grade)
    except Exception:
        currentgrades.append('No assignments found')
        continue
  dictionary = {"class1": currentgrades[0], "class2": currentgrades[1], "class3": currentgrades[2], "class4": currentgrades[3], "class5": currentgrades[4], "class6": currentgrades[5], "class7": currentgrades[6]}
  return dictionary

def run():
  dictionary = getData()
  time.sleep(60)
```

That script runs constantly and does what I want, but then in my other script, I don't know how to just call the dictionary variable.  When I use
`from getdata.py import dictionary` 
in the Flask-ask script it just runs the loop and constantly gets the data.  I just want the Flask-ask script to take the variable defined in the "run" function and then use it without running any of the actual scripts defined in the getdata script, which have already run and gotten the correct data.  If it matters, both scripts are running in Terminal on a MacBook.

Is there any way to do what I'm asking about, or are there any easier workarounds?  Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you include the getData function, in your question, please? Also, are you trying to get data multiple times for an alexa intent call? If so, why can't you get data before the call? Just trying to understand a little better so I can help.

Comment: I added the function to the question.  I am basically trying to combine multiple pieces of data and form a dictionary before an Alexa intent call.  Ideally I would like to get the data before the call, but since it changes frequently I think I need to get the data after the skill is invoked, and Alexa times out whenever I try to get the data.

Comment: I tried putting the getData() function before the script, and it ran once to initialize the script, but doesn't re-check the data every time I start a new session with Alexa (which makes sense, but it's still not what I want).  If I make this its own intent, it will just time out.  Is there any way to run this script that takes more than ten seconds to complete and get up-to-date data each time I ask Alexa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved.

As for the original question, I didn't figure out how to make it just import the dictionary instead of first running the function to generate the dictionary.  Furthermore, I realized there had to be a more practical solution than constantly running a script like that, and even then not getting brand new data.

My solution was to make the script that gets the data start running at the same time as the launch function.  Here was the final script for the first intent (the rest of it remained the same):

```
@ask.intent("start_skill")

def start_skill():
    welcome_message = 'What is the password?'
    thread = threading.Thread(target=getData, args=())
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
    return question(welcome_message)

def getData():
  #script to get data here

#other intents and rest of script here
```

By design, the skill requested a numeric passcode to make sure I was the one using it before it was willing to read the data (which was probably pointless, but this skill is at least as much for my own educational reasons as for practical reasons, so, for the extra practice, I wanted this to have as many features as I could possibly justify).  So, by the time you would actually be able to ask for the data, the script to get the data will have finished running (I have tested this and it seems to work without fail).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to import the function, so you can run it; rather than importing the dictionary.

try deleting the `run` function and then in your other script

```
from getdata import getData
```

Then each time you write `getData()` it will run your code and get a new up-to-date dictionary.

Is this what you were asking about?

Comment: Well, the problem is just that I don’t know how to get a new up-to-date dictionary without the Alexa script timing out. I have 8 seconds after Alexa runs an intent to return an answer before Alexa gives up waiting and returns an error, which isn’t enough to update the dictionary. So, I need to somehow update the dictionary between intents or something.

Comment: @ProgrammerWhoCannotProgram Same question, why can't you call getData() each time *before* creating the alexa intent, each time(i.e update dictionary between intents, as you said)?

Comment: @forumulator That's what I wanted to do, I just couldn't figure out how.  Once the intent is called, it runs a function, and I have 10 seconds to return a value (which ends the function).  I tried putting the script in between two intent definitions, but it just ran when I initialized the script and didn't actually run after the intent above it before the one below (as I should have expected).  My solution was to run it at the same time as the starting intent, so the starting intent can return its value but the getData() keeps going, and by the time you need the dictionary, it's finished.